# Creating an XML structure with dynamic element names using XSLT with XML input

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to take my XML document and transform it a different XML structure using XSLT.

Here's my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProcessData>
<FTPRemoteHost>RACHEL</FTPRemoteHost>
  <CodeListValues>
    <BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
      <PARM>CD</PARM>
      <VALUE>/Desktop/Rachel</VALUE>
      <DTM/>
    </BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
    <BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
      <PARM>FTPProfileName</PARM>
      <VALUE>1234567890</VALUE>
      <DTM>yyyyMMdd</DTM>
    </BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
    <BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
      <PARM>FileName1</PARM>
      <VALUE>Rachel.txt</VALUE>
      <DTM>yyyyMMdd</DTM>
    </BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
    <BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
      <PARM>MV/DEL</PARM>
      <VALUE>MOVE</VALUE>
      <DTM/>
    </BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
    <BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
      <PARM>SFG_MBX</PARM>
      <VALUE>/inbox/Rachel</VALUE>
      <DTM/>
    </BCBSRI_FTP_GET>
  </CodeListValues>
</ProcessData>
```

I've tried many different solutions I found here, but I'm unable to get my structure to appear the way I want it to. Here's my XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <resultSet> 
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </resultSet> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="ProcessData/CodeListValues">
        <xsl:for-each select="BCBSRI_FTP_GET">
            <xsl:value-of select="PARM"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="DTM"/>
        </xsl:for-each>      
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need the output to follow the following pattern:

```
<CD>/Desktop/Rachel</CD>
<FTPProfileName>1234567890</FTPProfileName>
<DTM>yyyyMMdd</DTM>
<FileName1>Rachel.txt</FileName1>
<DTM>yyyyMMdd</DTM>
<MV/DEL>MOVE</MV/DEL>
<SFG_MBX>/inbox/Rachel</SFG_MBX>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to create an element with a name specified from the `PARM` element, containing the value of `VALUE`. To do this you can use the `xsl:element` element

```
<xsl:element name="{PARM}">
    <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>
</xsl:element>
```

However, you won't be able to get the exact result your request because a `/` is not valid in an element name, and so `<MV/DEL>` is not a valid XML element. You will need to translate the `/` into something that is valid, perhaps?

Try this XSLT for starters though (this changes the `/` to a `-`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="ProcessData/CodeListValues">
        <xsl:for-each select="BCBSRI_FTP_GET">
            <xsl:element name="{translate(PARM, '/', '-')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:copy-of select="DTM[normalize-space()]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>      
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note that in your XSLT in your question you have two templates matching `/`. This is considered an error in XSLT, to have two templates matching the same thing with the same priority. XSLT's may either flag the error, or they may ignore all but the last template.

Also note the difference between `xsl:copy-of` and `xsl:value-of`. Using `xsl:copy-of` copies the whole node, whereas `xsl:value-of` just outputs the string value of it.